# knex Adonis Query: Transaction query already complete

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

I need to make a transaction:

First i create a new bookUnitQuestionOption, after i created i need to update other table (bookUnitQuestion) with the id that are saved.

I try something like:

```
async store ({ request }){
     const bookUnitQuestionOption = {...request.all(), user_id: request.user_id};
     const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()
     const responseInsercaoOption = BookUnitQuestionOption.create(bookUnitQuestionOption, trx)
     if(bookUnitQuestionOption.correct === true)
            await this.atualizaOptionCorreta(bookUnitQuestionOption.book_unit_question_id, responseInsercaoOption.id, trx)

     trx.commit() 
}

async atualizaOptionCorreta(bookUnitQuestionId, idOpcaoPergunta, transaction){
    await BookUnitQuestion.query()
        .where('id', bookUnitQuestionId)
        .update({correct_answer_description_id :idOpcaoPergunta}, transaction);
}
```

But i'm getting a 500 error:

> message: "Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx
>   for more info"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing await before the first query, second query is skipped because of if and trx.commit() is ran in that case before the first query is executed.

```
const responseInsercaoOption = BookUnitQuestionOption.create(bookUnitQuestionOption, trx)
```

should be:

```
const responseInsercaoOption = await BookUnitQuestionOption.create(bookUnitQuestionOption, trx)
```